# Redirect custom roles in WP to different places

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, custom-wordpress-pages

I've tried a number of things. Below is what I have so far in my functions.php and below that is what I have added to my custom login page called dashboard-login.php.
I've made a custom role called `employee`.
All of the privileges for employee have been set to `false`.
Essentially, if my admin role logs in, I would like it to go to `/wp-admin` and if an employee logs in, I'd like it to go to `/dashboard` *while* denying it access to `/wp-admin` and redirecting itself back to `/dashboard`.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'employee', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return '/dashboard';
        } else {
            return home_url("/dashboard");
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

and if I remove this function, that I also added, it sends the admin to `/dashboard` when I need it to go to `/wp-admin`.

```
function admin_default_page() {
    return home_url( '/admin' );
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Login page

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'redirect'    => home_URL("/dashboard"), 
    'id_username' => 'user',
    'id_password' => 'pass')
    ;
?>
```